# How to reduce the range detection interval in beacon for Android

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I have using **Android Beacon Library**  for one of my beacon solution . I can see that if I enter the beacon range ..it calls the **"didEnterRegion"** function but it never enter the **"didExitRegion"** when I go off the beacon region . I am taking the above code which I used in here [Android iBeacon App not working in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44971138/android-ibeacon-app-not-working-in-the-background/44972160) . In addition to that is there any way I can reduce the range detection because I keep on getting that very frequently because logically I want to record the data and send the notification once if customer enter beacons in 1 mt range.

Comment: Did you change the code based on the answer to the linked question?  Can you show how it looks now?

Comment: Not much change .. only change was to remove unbind in the onPause in MainActivity

Answer (score 1):

In the code shown in the other question, the didEnter Region method disables monitoring with `regionBootstrap.disable()`  If you don't want it disabled, remove that code.

```
@Override
public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Got a didEnterRegion call");
    // This call to disable will make it so the activity below only gets launched the first time a beacon is seen (until the next time the app is launched)
    // if you want the Activity to launch every single time beacons come into view, remove this call.
    regionBootstrap.disable();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    // Important:  make sure to add android:launchMode="singleInstance" in the manifest
    // to keep multiple copies of this activity from getting created if the user has
    // already manually launched the app.
    this.startActivity(intent);


}
```

If you don't want to send a notification until a user is < 1m, you must use the didRangeBeaconsInRegion callback, and then only fire the notification if `beacon.getDistance < 1.0`.

Comment: Hello David , Thanks for your response. I have opened a new thread for a different question if you could answer  it that would be great. ..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45142727/how-to-increase-the-delay-in-the-data-of-the-region-notifier